# Why combine produces a different behavior from readLines() function

Tags: r

I am learning R and so far I am not having any trouble in catching up besides the following problem that I am hopeful someone out there will help me to understand.

If I create a character vector in the following way `test1 <- c("a", "b", "c")`
I get one vector of type *character* and I can access to each member of the vector through an indexer `test1[n]`.

That makes sense and does what I understand it should do.

However if I do `test2 <- readLines("file1.txt")` where *file1.txt* contains one line (several random words space separated) I get one vector of class *character* (same as the first case) and I can't use an indexer (unless there's a way and I don't know about it yet).

Questions:

1. Why both are char type based but they are stored differently
2. How one could tell them apart without knowing how they have been created
3. Besides using a `strsplit()` is there a way to break it down like `c()` does at loading time from a file?

Any help to understand the insides of this language is wildly appreciated!

Comment: Try `scan("file1.txt", "", sep = " ")` instead of `readLines()` to get separated values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why both are char type based but they are stored differently

Both are stored in exactly the same way. R has no specific type to represent a single character and as a consequence characters are not a collections.

In the first case you have simply a character vector of length 3 where each element has size 1

```
test1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
typeof(test1)
# [1] "character"
length(test1)
# [1] 3
nchar(test1)
# [1] 1 1 1
```

and in the second case a character vector of length equal to number of lines in an input file and each element has size equal to length of string:

```
writeLines("foobar", con="file1.txt")
test2 <- readLines("file1.txt")
typeof(test2)
# [1] "character"
length(test2)
# [1] 1
nchar(test2)
# [1] 6
```

> Besides using a strsplit() is there a way to break it down like c() does at loading time from a file?

If you have fixed size elements you can try `readBin` but generally speaking `strisplit` is the way to go:

```
f <- "file1.txt"
readBin(f, what = 'raw', size = 1, n = file.info(f)$size) %>% sapply(rawToChar)
# [1] "f"  "o"  "o"  "b"  "a"  "r"  "\n"
```